# Can`t log in using stored procedure VB .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, stored-procedures, windows-forms-designer

hello everyone i started learning vb and im trying to do a login using windows form but everytime i try to log it says that user/password is wrong... ive checked the stored procedure and the value of the variables and everything seems ok.

on the login function ive checked the count value and it returns -1...dont know what i am missing :/ please some help

this is the login button

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    If txtUser.Text = "" And txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Fields are empty")
    Else
        If txtUser.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("User is empty")
        Else
            If txtPassword.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Password is empty")
            Else
                Dim dts As New cPerson
                dts.user = txtUser.Text
                dts.pass = txtPassword.Text
                If Login(dts) = True Then
                    Me.Hide()
                    Dim box = New Menu()
                    box.Show()
                Else
                    MsgBox("user/password is wrong")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

this is the login function

```
Public Shared Function Login(ByVal dts As cPerson) As Boolean
    Try
        conexion.Open()
        comando = New SqlCommand("SP_Login")
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        comando.Connection = conexion
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usu", dts.user)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pas", dts.pass)
        Dim cont As Integer = comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If (cont > 0) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    Finally
        conexion.Close()
    End Try
End Function
```

and finally the SP

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Login
@usu as varchar(15),
@pas as varchar(20)
as
select * from Person where user=@usu and password=@pas
```

Comment: My suggestion is that SP `SP_Login` get should return count of rows in table `Person`. Use `ExecuteScalar`. You should avoid passing password and username on the network as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think that calling `ExecuteNonQuery` to execute a query might be part of the problem?  A non-query is one or more SQL statements that do not retrieve records.  What does your SQL do?  It retrieves records.  You should be calling `ExecuteReader` and then testing the `HasRows` property to determine whether there was a match or not.  Alternatively, change your sproc to return a count and call `ExecuteScalar` to get that count.